# How to get small and large Icons from NotificationListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, notifications

I want to get the Icons from Notification posted of any apps in Mobile.

For this purpose, I have created NotificationListener Service and override the on notification Posted method.

I have tried the below methods but none of them is working. Please someone help I am new and leaner. Thanks in Advance.

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
        Intent intent = new  Intent("com.example.notify");
        intent.putExtra("Notification sbn", sbn);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
  
}


    public class ImageChangeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                StatusBarNotification sbn = intent.getParcelableExtra("Notification sbn");
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) sbn.getNotification().extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON);
                
                    image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                     image2.setImageBitmap(sbn.getNotification().largeIcon);
                Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
                notification.getLargeIcon();
                image3.setImageIcon(notification.getLargeIcon());
             
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use custom image witch i get in server and show in large view or any  size  need,.

my BroadcastReceiver  is :

```
public class CustomNotificationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

private   String channelID = "1";
private   String channelName = "news";
private   String channelDesc = "news description";

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;


    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    if (extra != null) {
        getNotification(modelNotification, null);

    }

}

public void getNotification(ModelNotification remoteMessage, Class<?> action_click) {
     Notification notification;
     NotificationManager notificationManager;

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getNotification   Notif Type:  if ");

         channelID = "1";
         channelName = "news";
         channelDesc = "news description";
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDesc);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

    }

        RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext,
                RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)).play();

    NotificationCompat.Builder   builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channelID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotifTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotifBody())
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 500, 500, 500, 500})
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    if (remoteMessage.getDataImage() != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(remoteMessage.getDataImage());
        builder.setStyle(
                new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(bitmap)
                        .bigLargeIcon(null)
        ).setLargeIcon(bitmap);
    }


    notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(notfiId,  notification);

  

}


public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("awesome", "Error in getting notification image: " + 
      e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
      }
    }
```

> i use this method for handle image getBitmapfromUrl()

happy coding :)